# Connecting to prod database using scalingo's URL python

Tags: python, mysql, database, url, flask

It's my first time puting a website to prod, I decided to use scalingo but I can't get how to use the database URL.
They said to me that using `os.getenv("DATABASE_URL")` will get me this shapped url : mysql://username:password@host:port/databasename?options 
I'm using

```
 app.config['MYSQL_HOST'] = 'localhost'
   app.config['MYSQL_USER'] = 'root'
   app.config['MYSQL_PASSWORD'] = ''
   app.config['MYSQL_DB'] = 'xxxxxxx'
   mysql = MySQL(app)
```

To connect to my local database, how can I link these two ?
Any help welcomed :)

Comment: What extension are you using for MySQL?

Comment: i'm using flask_mysqldb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`urllib` is probably the easiest way to break it down into it's components:

```
from urllib.parse import urlparse
import os

uri = urlparse(os.getenv('DATABASE_URL'))

print(uri.port)
print(uri.username)
print(uri.password)
print(uri.hostname)
print(uri.path)  # database (might need to crop the /): uri.path[1:]
```